# Theos not being installed in ios 6.0

Tags: jailbreak, theos

I have used `installtheos3` command from mobile terminal as root user to install Theos in my IOS, but not able to see theos folder inside /var directory.It was present before i restarted my device but after that its gone.
I have tried to install multiple time, the installation process gets completed successfully but no theos folder comes in /var .It is not visible even in cydia package.and i am note able to create any project usnig theos the below error comes.

-sh /var /theos/bin/nic.pl: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Delete /var/theos if it exists if you have the package from cydia remove it. **//IMPORTANT///If you opened cydia recently respring your device to close it(closing from the switcher doesnt work)\IMPORTANT\**. Now run "installsdk3" without quotes it will install theos and the headers on your device(no need to class-dump or download headers!!) After it has completed reboot. Theos will now be installed, works for me on iOS6